# Terraform: Local variable reference

Tags: terraform

I have something like so:

```
locals {
   a = var.from_scratch
   b = a == "true"? 5 : 56
}
```

Apparently, this is not a valid Terraform syntax. I cannot use `a` on the condition that decides `b`. This is a very simple example but this would be very handy for more complex expression e.g. the evaluation of `a` is more involved. Is there any way to do that in Terraform? I get `Invalid reference`.

Comment: do you only want to evaluate based on true/false? you can use something like this:

`locals {
   a = var.from_scratch
   b = local.a ? 5 : 56
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `local` even in the `locals` block:

```
locals {
   a = var.from_scratch
   b = local.a == "true"? 5 : 56
}
```

but do keep in mind that currently you are comparing `local.a` to a literal `"true"`, whereas you probably just want the boolean `true`.

```
locals {
   a = var.from_scratch
   b = local.a == true ? 5 : 56
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on using the local `a` variable elsewhere in the code, the code can be modified like this:

```
locals {
   b = var.from_scratch ? 5 : 56
}
```

As a side note, unless you have defined the `from_scratch` variable as string, the comparison from your question will not work. There is also [`bool` type](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#bool) in terraform, so you should use that instead of using a variable of type string and setting it to `"true"`.